# How to spread names of a table

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I group the names based on keys, Does it work using `spread` function in tidyverse?

```
    example <- tribble(
  ~key, ~names,
  "t1", "name1",
  "t1", "name2",
  "t2", "name3",
  "t2", "name4",
  "t4", "name5"
)

example %>% spread(key, names)
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2), (3, 4)

desired output

t1  name1,name2
t2  name3,name4
t4  name5
```

Comment: Is your desired output a data frame? What type is the second column? character or list?

Comment: @pisdom; yes a dataframe with a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spread` is used for pivoting/reshaping table and normally it requires three columns (id column, header column and value column) to give meaningful result; To get your desired output, you can group by *key* and summarize *names* to a list:

```r
example %>% 
    group_by(key) %>% 
    summarise(names = list(names)) %>% 
    as.data.frame()    # for print purpose only

#  key        names
#1  t1 name1, name2
#2  t2 name3, name4
#3  t4        name5
```

Or maybe a two-way table:

```r
table(example)

#    names
#key  name1 name2 name3 name4 name5
#  t1     1     1     0     0     0
#  t2     0     0     1     1     0
#  t4     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: @Pisdom: thank you. However, the original data I have some other names in the second column and this code is returning indices in the output like `c(1,2) or c(1,3,4)` etc instead of `name1,name2` or `name1,name3,name4`.

Comment: You may have `names` as factors, try `names = list(as.character(names))` in `summarise`.

Comment: Thanks it works but it looks like this `c("name1", "name2")`. How can I get rid off double quotes and `c()`.

Comment: By summarizing `names` as lists, each element is a vector, which is why you have `c()`. I didn't get `c()` as above. It's solely a print issue. If you want them to be printed as strings, you can summarize the result as strings. i.e. `names = toString(as.character(names))`.